# Windows 10 Install Problems

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-installation

I haven't been asking in a while, but I accidentally deleted (yes, formatted) my windows 10 partition. I only have my Linux Mint 18 ext4 partition, so I tried writing a windows 10 official ISO to my USB using UnetBootIn. It works boots fine, and I see the spinning loading icon. However, as it goes into install, nothing happens. It just sits at the dark-purple background and just stalls. I can open up CMD using shift-F10, and I can run setup manually, but then there are now two setup.exe and stalls at "setup is starting". The mouse also changes into the hourglass. I urgently need help, as many of my school programs can't run on wine.

Comment: What was the native version of Windows? Install that? Is there a recovery partition?  "  Free upgrade ended.

Comment: @TonyStewart Free upgrade has what to do with installing Windows 10?

Comment: @Ramhound If you don't have the Retail installer or recovery partition .... everything

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-windows_install/after-the-windows-10-free-upgrade-is-over-what-are/38e69c1b-cd39-417c-a4ae-17bde9b3fa43

Comment: No recovery, microsoft (non-oem) iso |  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO | and I didn't get a native OS CD with my P34WV3.

Comment: @TonyStewart - "If you don't have the Retail installer " - Easy enough to download.

Comment: What was the native version of Windows? Install that? Is there a recovery partition? Did you try this? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

Comment: ok ramhound then why does it fail?

Comment: I don't have a retail installer...

Comment: If anyone could respond, it would be very helpful. More information: the native version is Windows 10, no recovery, and yes, I used your exact link.